# How to replace image in file system and url database upload file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload, edit

I have the code to save the image file uploads as follows, I have difficulty while in the edit form, how to change the image that was uploaded them? What code should be added in the edit function?

## Model > EmployeeServices.cs

```
 public class EmployeeModel
    {

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Position ID")]
        public int PositionID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter NO PEK")]
        public string NoPEK { get; set; }

        public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

## Controller : Upload File

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateEmployee(EmployeeModel org, string Command, HttpPostedFileBase AvatarUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return PartialView("_CreateEmployee", org);
            }
            else
            {

                Employee orgObj = new Employee();
                orgObj.PositionID = org.PositionID;
                orgObj.NoPEK = org.NoPEK;
                orgObj.AvatarUrl = org.AvatarUrl;

                var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/upload"), filename);
                image.Save(path);
                orgObj.AvatarUrl = Url.Content(Path.Combine("/Content/upload", filename));


                bool IsSuccess = mobjModel.AddEmployee(orgObj);
                if (IsSuccess)
                {
                    TempData["OperStatus"] = "Employee added succeessfully";
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    return RedirectToAction("IndexEmployee", "Employees");
                }

                return PartialView("_CreateEmployee");
            }
        }
```

## Controller : Edit File

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateEmployee(EmployeeModel org, string Command)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return PartialView("_EditEmployee", org);
            }
            else
            {
                Employee orgObj = new Employee();
                orgObj.EmployeeID = org.EmployeeID;
                orgObj.PositionID = org.PositionID;
                orgObj.NoPEK = org.NoPEK;
                orgObj.AvatarUrl = org.AvatarUrl;


                bool IsSuccess = mobjModel.UpdateEmployee(orgObj);
                if (IsSuccess)
                {
                    TempData["OperStatus"] = "Employee updated succeessfully";
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    return RedirectToAction("IndexEmployee", "Employees");
                }
            }

            return PartialView("_EditEmployee");
        }
```